# Nested ForLoop In PartialView not working using MVC 5 ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, for-loop, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a Model where Recipes have corresponding RecipeLines, I am trying to print out a list of those Recipes looping through the RecipeLines that have a corresponding RecipeID for that particular Recipe. I'm almost there...

Here are the Models

**Models/Recipe.cs**

```
namespace XXX.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        public string RecipeInstructions { get; set; }
        public int Serves { get; set; }
        public float PrepTime { get; set; }

        public virtual List<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Models/RecipeLine.cs**

```
namespace XXX.Models
{
    public class RecipeLine
    {
        public int RecipeLineID { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public float MeasureAmount { get; set; }
        public int MeasurementID { get; set; }
        public string Instruction { get; set; }

        public int RecipeID { get; set; }
        public int IngredientID { get; set; }

        public virtual Measurement Measurement { get; set; }
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Models/Measurement.cs**

```
namespace XXX.Models
{
    public class Measurement
    {
        public int MeasurementID { get; set; }
        public string Measurement { get; set; }

        public virtual List<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Models/Ingredient.cs**

```
namespace XXX.Models
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        public int IngredientID { get; set; }
        public string IngredientName { get; set; }
        public string IngredientDescript { get; set; }

        public virtual List<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel

**ViewModels/RecipeLineViewModel.cs**

```
namespace XXX.ViewModels
{
    public class RecipeLineViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Recipe> AllRecipes { get; set; }
        //public IEnumerable<RecipeLine> AllRecipeLines { get; set; }

        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public void PopulateModel()
        {
            AllRecipes = db.Recipes.Include("RecipeLines")
           .Include("RecipeLines.Measurement")
           .Include("RecipeLines.Ingredient");
        }
    }
}
```

My Partial Controller

**Controllers/Partial.cs**

```
using XXX.ViewModels;
using XXX.Models;

namespace XXX.Controllers
{
    public class PartialsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult RecipeList()
        {
            RecipeLineViewModel model = new RecipeLineViewModel();
            model.PopulateModel();

            return PartialView("_RecipeList", model);
        }
    }
}
```

OK, Now for the PartialView that is giving me problems during the NESTED FOR LOOP. The FIRST FOR LOOP is working fine. It's the NESTED LOOP that I obviously have wrong

**Partials/_RecipeList.cshtml**

```
@model XXX.ViewModels.RecipeLineViewModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <h4>Recipes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
         { @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Recipe") }</h4>
        <p>Our recipes are a combination of meals we have put together using our own products and meals our customers have submitted of their own creation using our products!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>@*Blank column*@
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <h4>Select a Recipe</h4>
        @foreach (var recipe in Model.AllRecipes)
        {
            <a href="#@recipe.RecipeName" class="small button">@recipe.RecipeName</a>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var recipe in Model.AllRecipes)
{
    <div class="row" id="@recipe.RecipeName"><div class="large-12 columns"><hr /></div></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/recipes/" + recipe.RecipeImage)))
            { <img src="~/Images/recipes/@recipe.RecipeImage"> }
            else
            { <h5>No image available</h5> }
            <br /><br />
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                <div class="row"><div class="large-12 columns"><strong>UPDATE RECIPE: </strong> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Recipe", new { id = recipe.RecipeID }, null) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Recipe", new { id = recipe.RecipeID }, null) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Recipe", new { id = recipe.RecipeID }, null)</div></div>
            }
        </div>

        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <h4>@recipe.RecipeName / @recipe.RecipeName</h4>
            <div>
                Prep Time: @recipe.PrepTime Mins / Serves: @recipe.Serves People
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
                { @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Recipe", null, null, "Serves", new { id = recipe.RecipeID }, null) }

            </div>
            <br /><strong>Ingredients:</strong><br /><br />
            @foreach (RecipeLine recipeLines in Model.RecipeLines.Where(rl => rl.RecipeID == recipe.RecipeID))
            {
                <div>
                    @if (recipeLines.Quantity != "0")
                    {
                        @recipeLines.Quantity }
                    @if (recipeLines.MeasureAmount != 0)
                    {
                        @recipeLines.MeasureAmount }
                    @if (recipeLines.Measurement.Measurement != "none")
                    {
                        @recipeLines.Measurement.Measurement }
                    @recipeLines.Ingredient.IngredientName @recipeLines.Instruction
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "RecipeLines", new { id = recipeLines.RecipeLineID }, null);
                    }
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "RecipeLines", new { id = recipeLines.RecipeLineID }, null) }
                </div>
            }
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
            { @Html.ActionLink("+", "Create", "RecipeLines", new { recipeid = recipe.RecipeID }, null);
            }
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <strong>Instructions:</strong>
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Recipe", null, null, "Instructions", new { id = recipe.RecipeID }, null);
            }
            <br /><br />
            <div>@Html.Raw(recipe.RecipeInstructions.Replace("\n", "<br />"))</div><br />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If that is too much code for you to look at Here is a shortened version that get's the same point across..

Abbreviated Code for 
**Partials/_RecipeList.cshtml**

```
@model XXX.ViewModels.RecipeLineViewModel
@foreach (var recipe in Model.AllRecipes)
{
@recipe.RecipeName

    @foreach (var recipeLines in Model.AllRecipes.RecipeLines.Where(rl => rl.RecipeID == recipe.RecipeID))
    {
    @recipeLines.Measurement.Measurement
    @recipeLines.Ingredient.IngredientName
    @recipeLines.Instruction
    }
}
```

Yes I am a total noob when it comes to this type of operation. I would like to understand it better, but I have been struggling to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. I know I'm almost there.

**Here is the current error:**

[image]

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Oops sorry, let me give you the error. I didn't think it was important because I know my syntax is wrong.

Comment: I updated it. But Like I said, the problem is probably just my syntax.  Maybe the ViewModel. But I think it's the syntax in the nested for loop.

Comment: Your code samples are not consistent.  Your error message shows code that occurs in none of your code samples.  Your error message clearly tells you that you are referencing a property that doesn't exist on your model.  Then the second error says that model doesn't exist - I suspect you are mixing examples and error messages.

Comment: I had shortened some stuff up for brevity. The problem is in the syntax of the ForLoop The Names of the properties I am displaying on the page looked different only because I was shortening the code for brevity I fixed that. but that is not my problem.

Comment: I do appreciate you pointing it out though. Sorry to confuse.

Comment: I think what Nathan is trying to say is that your error doesn't match up with your code. Look carefully at both of them and you'll see that you didn't include the correct lines.

Comment: Ill post an image of the error

Comment: Again, analyze the error lines, then look at the code you've given for `Partials/_RecipeList.cshtml`. You will see they don't match, meaning you've given the wrong code for us to look at.

Comment: I had to shorten the code I make available for brevity. The problem is with the nested for loop. The syntax is wrong. The error is provided to give you an idea of what is wrong with my implementation of the nested for loop. If you want I will provide the code verbatim, but I don't see how it will help because the code within the for loop brackets is not the problem it's the `var recipeLines in Model.AllRecipes.RecipeLines.Where...` line that is wrong. Let me know if what I have provided now helps any.

Comment: There you go! That is the actual page. I tried to make it simple because the guts of this code is not the problem its the one line setting up the nested for loop. But if you want to see it all there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have this...

```
@foreach (RecipeLine recipeLines in Model.RecipeLines.Where(rl => rl.RecipeID == recipe.RecipeID))
        {
...
```

The offending line specified by the error `Model Contains no definition for RecipeLines` is this...

```
Model.RecipeLines.Where(rl => rl.RecipeID == recipe.RecipeID)
```

You need to change that to this

```
recipe.RecipeLines.Where(rl => rl.RecipeID == recipe.RecipeID)
```

`recipe` comes from the outer loop, and `RecipeLines` is coming from your `Recipe` class

Comment: Let me give this a spin and let you know what happens.. I appreciate you hanging in there and helping out.

Comment: Im going to change your solution a bit. But you got me there!

Comment: @EricB The kicker is that I was able to solve this in a couple seconds once you posted the appropriate information. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx for information on writing good questions.